# Changing Seperator color in Fabric UI

Tags: reactjs, office-fabric

In the [Separator](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/separator#feedback) control documentation for Microsoft's Fabric UI, the Separator is a simple control that separates content and allows content inside the Separator, while allowing some customization options.

There doesn't seem to be a way to change the color of the actual separator line. I need to do this as the background color of my app is almost exactly the same as the color of the separator line.

I have tried every possible styling solution in the documentation. I've tried setting color, borderColor, outlineColor, etc, on the `styles.root` property. I've played with the `semanticColors` portion of the `theme` property, and so far I've come up with nothing.

Internally, it seems that the line is created as a `:before` before the text and the `background-color` is what determines the color. I can't find a way to alter this, though.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: I've updated my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to overwrite the css. The background color of the separator is set in `.root-*::before` which changes, so you can't use `.root-45::before` as this might change to `.root-56::before` in a different browser. use [[attribute^=value] Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp)

> The [attribute^=value] selector matches every element whose attribute value begins with a specified value.

**UPDATE**

You can also create a styles object and pass it to the component.

```
const styles = {
  root: [{
    selectors: { // add selectors here
      '::before': {
        background: 'blue',
      },
    }
  }]
};

<Separator styles={styles}>Today</Separator>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/office-ui-fabric-react.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

const { Separator, PrimaryButton } = window.Fabric;

const styles = {
  root: [{
    selectors: {
      '::before': {
        background: 'blue',
      },
    }
  }]
};

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
    name: 'Hello React'
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
      <PrimaryButton>I am a button Hello</PrimaryButton>
      <Separator styles={styles}>Today</Separator>
      <Separator>Now</Separator>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to this with SCSS?